# EJB creation with @Singletone annotation ejb3.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have the following structure:

```
@Stateless
public class BasicCMIRP {
    @EJB 
    private MyDummyBean basicMXBeanz;
}
```

next class

```
@Singleton
public class MyDummyBean {
}
```

This works all right, 
but if I change it and make `MyDummyBean` implement `DynamicMBean`
like this:

```
@Singleton
public class MyDummyBean implements DynamicMBean { 
    // ... implementation methods go here
}
```

I receive `Can not create Bean BasicCMIRP` , exception in the log, why is this?

In the past I had `MyDummyBean` to implement `DynamicMBean` and made this class singleton by marking the constructor private and creating a static `getInstance()` method, but with the new Java EE 6 I wanted to use the new annotation to make my life easier, but something is not working as I expect it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: ah i am new to stackoverflow, never bothered about it bit will now accept the answers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: if the bean implements more than one interface it had to be marked with
@LocalBean.

Comment: That's only partially true. If your bean implements a business interface AND you want to inject it by class instead of by interface THEN you need `LocalBean`. In class `BasicCMIRP` you are injecting `MyDummyBean` by class, not by its interface `DynamicMBean`. That was your core problem.

Comment: More specifically, when a bean implements no interfaces, it's default client view is `LocalBean`, and when a bean implements exactly one interface (outside some javax.ejb and java.io interfaces), it's default client view is that local interface.